# Authentication with SASL using JAAS VS librdkafka oAuthBearer

Tags: apache-kafka, oauth-2.0, jaas, librdkafka

We have a kafkaProducer cpp application, which will send data to kafkaBrokers which are configured to authenticate using JAAS-OAUTHBEARER.

- Can I use JAAS with cpp kafkaProducer which uses librdkafka ?
- Without JAAS (with oauth mechanism of librdkafka) Can I produce data to brokers which is  JAAS configured ?

**Kafka producer configs:**

```
SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required"
```

```
SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG =  "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
```

```
sasl.mechanism = "OAUTHBEARER"
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = OAuthClientCallbackHandler.class.getName()
```

**Kafka client**

```
rd_kafka_conf_set (conf, "bootstrap.servers", brokers)
rd_kafka_conf_set (conf, "security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
rd_kafka_conf_set (conf, "sasl.mechanism", "OAUTHBEARER")
rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb(conf, token_refresh_cb_fun)
```

Can these two connect and send data using oauth mechanism ?

Answer (score 1):

JKS / JAAS is Java specific. The broker runs Java, so yes, it's required there.

For non-Java ***clients***, no, you cannot use it, and you need X.509 certificates along with other SASL configs such as

```
sasl.oauthbearer.config
sasl.oauthbearer.client.id
sasl.oauthbearer.client.secret
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url
sasl.oauthbearer.method
sasl.oauthbearer.scope
```

Comment: Okay, I can't use JAAS in librdkafka. Is second question is possible ?

Comment: What second question? Yes, librdkafka with Oauth settings can send to a Kafka broker that has JAAS settings